# determining all solutions to trigonometric equations within the given constraints

Tags: trigonometry

So, in Trig, I've generally been pretty good with doing the algebra that will bring me to my zeros, but after that determining the other solutions (when given constraints) is pretty hit or miss for me because I feel I don't have a strong grasp of finding all the solutions with constraints.

Example:

$5\sin((\pi/3)\theta)=3$

Solve for the four smallest positive solutions accurate to 2 decimals.

The 4 solutions I calculated were (2 were correct):

$x_1 = .572958$

$x_2 = .614498$

$x_3 = 6.572958$

$x_4 = 6.614498$

I started with $\arcsin(3/5)$ as reference angle and looked for other coterminal angles in quadrants 1 and 2 because $\sin(\theta)$ was positive in quadrant 1. Accomplished adding or subtracting increments of $2\pi$ or $\pi$. As the equations become more complex, I keep being unable to find 1 or 2 of the 3 or 4 solutions to the problem.

Can someone help me work out where my method is failing?

Comment: Click on the circled "?" on the far right of the top bar. Choose the Help Center. In the middle column of Help Center, under "Our Model", choose "How Can I Format Mathematics Here?"

Comment: thank you, that looks much nicer!

Comment: Another tip: If you right-click on any text in an answer or comment and  hover over "Show Text As" and glide to the right and down one line to left-click on "Tex Commands", then it will show the LaTeX code.

Answer (score 1):

$\theta$ is a solution if and only if $(\pi/3)\theta=\arcsin(3/5)+2k\pi$ or $(\pi/3)\theta=\pi-\arcsin(3/5)+2k\pi$, for some integer $k$.

Comment: do you mean that   $arcsin(3/5)$  was not a solution in this case?? I meant when I started with $arcsin(3/5)$ that was the zero I got after the algebra. I then set $arcsin^1(3/5)$ = to $\pi/3x$ which was the first solution.

Also, I may have discovered my problem from your post, I have never found a solution by taking $\pi - \theta$ then adding $2k\pi$ to it. Why do we begin with one of the solutions as $\pi - \theta$ here??

Comment: Yes $\arcsin(3/5)$ is a solution, look at what I wrote above with the special case $k=0$. I ve used nothing more than the fact : the equation $\sin(x)=a$ has solutions $\arcsin(a)+2k\pi$, $\pi-\arcsin(a)+2k\pi$, where $k$ is an integer (so infinitely many solutions). Now that you have all the solutions, you just have to find out the smallest positive ones.